# direct admin, run cron only in week-days

Tags: cron, directadmin

I want to set up cronjob in the Direct Admin panel only while week-days without Sundays and Saturdays. additionally I need run this 3 time a day no certain hours. Can I do that with 1 command?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. To take care of running things only on weekdays, enter a range in the Day of Week field. 0=Sunday, so you want "1-5" in that field. To run a command multiple times, you would use commas to separate the hours you want it to run. For example, to run at 0100, 0900, and 1700, enter "1,9,17" in the Hour field and "0" in the minute field.